# Using Case and To_Char

Tags: sql, oracle

Could someone help me with the below?

```
select  CASE ( TO_CHAR (creation_date ,'MON')
 WHEN 'JAN' THEN 1
 WHEN 'FEB' THEN 2
 WHEN 'MAR' THEN 3
 WHEN 'APR' THEN 4 
 ELSE 'NULL') AS PERIOD 
from po_line_locations_all
```

I am getting error message -

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>   00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis".

I am no expert so if someone could help me with the above.

Many thanks
Dan

Comment: `select  CASE  TO_CHAR (creation_date ,'MON')
 WHEN 'JAN' THEN 1
 WHEN 'FEB' THEN 2
 WHEN 'MAR' THEN 3
 WHEN 'APR' THEN 4 
 ELSE 'NULL' END AS PERIOD 
from po_line_locations_all`

Comment: @TonyAndrews - what you posted is actually an answer (it also happens to be the correct answer) - you may want to repost as such.

Comment: @mathguy: I have now!

Comment: HI @TonyAndrews i now get the following? - ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Comment: See my answer below - it is the `'NULL'`

Answer (score 2):

You need an `END`, and you don't need the parentheses:

```
select  CASE  TO_CHAR (creation_date ,'MON')
 WHEN 'JAN' THEN 1
 WHEN 'FEB' THEN 2
 WHEN 'MAR' THEN 3
 WHEN 'APR' THEN 4 
 ELSE NULL END AS PERIOD 
from po_line_locations_all;
```

Also `NULL` should not be quoted.  In fact the `ELSE` is superfluous, as `NULL` is the default anyway:

```
select  CASE  TO_CHAR (creation_date ,'MON')
 WHEN 'JAN' THEN 1
 WHEN 'FEB' THEN 2
 WHEN 'MAR' THEN 3
 WHEN 'APR' THEN 4 
 END AS PERIOD 
from po_line_locations_all;
```

Comment: Hi Tony,  It wasn't the fact of the 'null' it doesn't like the number value as it is using TO_char. I.E then '1', '2', '3'. But you Pointed me in the right direction so thanks!

Comment: Well, that is the other side of the same coin - now all your values are strings.  But do you **really** want to return the 4-character string 'NULL' in the `else`?

Comment: It was more of a test query. I will use the period 1-12, then else 13.

Comment: Which month will not appear in the first 12? :-)

Comment: Why not use @vercelli's answer but simply like this: `select
extract(MONTH from creation_date) from po_line_locations_all;`

Comment: We have an ADJ period which in our accounting calendar comes under period 13

Comment: OK, so you are not really doing a CASE based on the 12 possible values of `TO_CHAR(creation_date ,'MON')` then?  Because you'd never get 'ADJ' back from that.

Comment: I didn't think of that! I will have to have a look at my code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Tony Andrews got it right, but I wouldn't go for `to_char` `'MON'` since it depends on you language. I'd go for `extract`

```
 select
     Case 
       when extract(MONTH from creation_date ) > 4 then NULL
       else extract(MONTH from creation_date )  end AS PERIOD
  from po_line_locations_all;
```

This is why it's a bad idea:

```
 alter session set NLS_LANGUAGE = 'ENGLISH';
 select extract(MONTH from sysdate) extr, to_char(sysdate,'MON') tochar from dual;
 alter session set NLS_LANGUAGE = 'SPANISH';
 select extract(MONTH from sysdate) extr, to_char(sysdate,'MON') tochar from dual;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Session altered.
      EXTR TOCHAR
---------- ------
         8 AUG

Session altered.
      EXTR TOCHAR
---------- ------
         8 AGO
```

Comment: Hi Vercelli, Thanks for the above. However the reason for using them individually is to be able to return a value for each month. i.e DEC - 12. This will represent the period that they are using.